# you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the "controller.service_arguments"?

Tags: php, symfony

I am beginner to symfony. When I calling get API in symphony,Showing error like below.

```
RuntimeException
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
Could not resolve argument $salesteamRepository of "App\Controller\SalesController::index()", maybe you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the "controller.service_arguments"?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your version of symfony.
in version 6 (and maybe 5.4 as well) you don't need any extra config other then autowire: true and autoconfigure: true.

in older versions you have to tell the framework to treat your controllers as controllers with method autowiring:

```
# controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html

Answer (score 6):

Its happen because your current class not act as service and everything class that you use in your class not automatically injection by symfony.

If you want automatically dependency injection for your all class that you made you can extend your class to `AbstractController`, like this

```
class MyPet extends AbstractController{}
```

This already mention in official symfony docs.

> In Symfony, a controller does not need to be registered as a service.
> But if you're using the default services.yaml configuration, and your
> controllers extend the AbstractController class, they are
> automatically registered as services. This means you can use
> dependency injection like any other normal service.

Answer (score 1):

Since [Symfony 5.3](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/controller/service.html) you can mark controllers with PHP attribute.

```php
#[AsController]
final class HomepageController
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing a similiar problem. This error description also gets thrown if you have a non-existent variable in your controller function.

For example, I followed the SymfonyCasts tutorial for Cauldron Overflow, but changed the name for the variables in the URL:

```php
/**
* @Route("/comments/{comment_id}/vote/{direction}")
*/
public function comment_vote(string $id, string $direction): JsonResponse 
{
    [...]
}
```

As you can see, the url uses `{comment_id}` and `{direction}` but the function takes `$id` and `$direction`. This means you have to change `string $id` to `string $comment_id` for it to work.

```php
/**
* @Route("/comments/{comment_id}/vote/{direction}")
*/
public function comment_vote(string $comment_id, string $direction): JsonResponse
{
    [...]
}
```